# TortoiseHg: Has a changeset been pushed?

Tags: mercurial, commit, push, tortoisehg, changeset

I have been working on a branch and have made some commits. Now is there some way I can see in TortoiseHg if those commits have been pushed or are they still just local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tortoise HG you can use the 'Determine and Mark outoing changesets' button (a green up-arrow with **no** horizontal bar) in TortoiseHG explorer.
This will compare the local changeset to the changesets on the currently selected server.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `hg outgoing` to see what would be sent if you pushed, and if a changeset doesn't show up in that list then it has been pushed to the specific remote repository you're testing.

There's no general "has been pushed" flag on a changeset because they can be pushed to multiple locations so it's not terribly meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is good to know (+1). I am marking the other answer as the correct one, since I wanted to know how to do it in Tortoise.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer on newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937021/tortoisehg-display-commits-that-are-not-pushed#11937133): The code that has been pushed will have "public" as its phase. The code that has not been pushed will be shown as "draft".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Praveen I think I did that.