# TortoiseHg - display commits that are not pushed

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

It's happened more than a few times that I'll commit a bit of code, then forget to actually push the code over to our remote repository (until my boss tells me that XYZ still doesn't work, and I feel silly).

Is there any way to have Tortoise display committed code that hasn't been pushed differently?  Ideally I'd love it if there was a way to get such changesets to show with a gray background or something.

So in the below screenshot, if revision 1270 had not been pushed, have that show up shaded, or marked somehow.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that has been pushed will have "public" as its phase.  The code that has not been pushed will be shown as "draft".

Comment: Ahh - neat, thank you!  I don't suppose there's any way to have draft codesets be displayed differently?

Comment: @AdamRackis Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sync toolbar](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.4/workbench.html#sync-toolbar) to view what "outgoing" changesets you have.

Comment: True -- I was more looking for something that'd always be visible - so if I thought I had pushed, it would jump out at me and I'd know that maybe I'm moving a bit too fast.